# Pandas: How to extract and calculate the number of "hour" per row in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-engineering

I have a data frame representing the schedule of some restaurants in a week.

- **What i want to do is to add a column `week_hours` to my initial Dataframe `df` that represents the total number of hours the restaurant is open per week.**

**The Data** (generated with `df.head(20).to_dict('split')`)

The days of the weeks in this example are in French
[image]

```
{'index': [0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  10,
  11,
  12,
  13,
  14,
  15,
  16,
  17,
  18,
  19],
 'columns': ['restaurant_id',
  'lundi',
  'mardi',
  'mercredi',
  'jeudi',
  'vendredi',
  'samedi',
  'dimanche'],
 'data': [['lCwqJWMxvIUQt1Re_tDn4w',
   '0:0-0:0',
   '0:0-0:0',
   '0:0-0:0',
   '0:0-0:0',
   '0:0-0:0',
   '0:0-0:0',
   '0:0-0:0'],
  ['pd0v6sOqpLhFJ7mkpIaixw',
   '11:0-20:0',
   '11:0-20:0',
   '11:0-20:0',
   '11:0-20:0',
   '11:0-22:0',
   '11:0-22:0',
   '11:0-17:0'],
  ['0vhi__HtC2L4-vScgDFdFw',
   '11:30-22:0',
   '11:30-22:0',
   '11:30-22:0',
   '11:30-22:0',
   '11:30-22:0',
   '12:0-22:0',
   '16:30-21:30'],
  ['t65yfB9v9fqlhAkLnnUXdg',
   '11:30-21:0',
   '11:30-21:0',
   '11:30-21:0',
   '11:30-21:0',
   '11:30-21:0',
   nan,
   '11:30-21:0'],
  ['i7_JPit-2kAbtRTLkic2jA',
   '11:30-22:0',
   '11:30-22:0',
   '11:30-23:0',
   '11:30-23:0',
   '11:30-23:0',
   nan,
   nan],
  ['vMh4madPU3qhNX7P7d8WGA', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
  ['BsvCTCVG7lrzXZ68VyyIcg',
   '0:0-0:0',
   '11:0-2:30',
   '11:0-2:30',
   '11:0-2:30',
   '11:0-2:30',
   '11:0-2:30',
   '11:0-2:30'],
  ['es3Fq9KNp6Ry994x4T4ZYg',
   '6:30-16:0',
   '6:30-16:0',
   '6:30-16:0',
   '6:30-16:0',
   '6:30-16:0',
   '7:0-14:0',
   nan],
  ['Xb7jOAa17xtT_uA4sCCAsg', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
  ['1vrrpIhpK628PUA0XWWd8g',
   '9:0-18:0',
   '9:0-18:0',
   '9:0-18:0',
   '9:0-18:0',
   '9:0-18:0',
   '9:0-18:0',
   '9:0-18:0'],
  ['NYKxikYKbkacWumJ82TxzA',
   '11:0-2:0',
   '11:0-2:0',
   '11:0-2:0',
   '11:0-2:0',
   '11:0-2:0',
   '11:0-2:0',
   '11:0-2:0'],
  ['4sRJvmKh43AqMRrjdwEdwA',
   '11:0-22:0',
   '11:0-22:0',
   '11:0-22:0',
   '11:0-22:0',
   '11:0-23:0',
   '11:0-23:0',
   '11:0-23:0'],
  ['laac2uH1lQVzBjKFUjuA1Q',
   '7:0-14:0',
   '7:0-14:0',
   '7:0-14:0',
   '7:0-14:0',
   '7:0-14:0',
   '7:0-14:0',
   '8:0-14:0'],
  ['vVOoL5H8Fr-qlQv-_DdoMA',
   '10:0-22:0',
   '10:0-22:0',
   '10:0-22:0',
   '10:0-22:0',
   '10:0-23:0',
   '10:0-23:0',
   '10:0-22:0'],
  ['k1c4gg8Ri5dre6ruPUKxJQ',
   '9:0-21:30',
   '9:0-21:30',
   '9:0-21:30',
   '9:0-21:30',
   '9:0-22:30',
   '9:0-22:30',
   '12:0-21:0'],
  ['x9f9NBMweyyjCQHuc9K4sw',
   '11:0-17:0',
   '10:0-17:0',
   '10:0-17:0',
   '10:0-17:0',
   '10:0-18:0',
   '10:0-18:0',
   nan],
  ['KWfLQddMBZNoh1bVcgASfA',
   '12:0-23:0',
   '12:0-23:0',
   '12:0-23:0',
   '12:0-23:0',
   '12:0-23:0',
   '12:0-23:0',
   '12:0-23:0'],
  ['4ScLXRii_WwBn5PbGBI-eg', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
  ['LAswzVTnT3uCvnKr-SwxEg', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
  ['G_wqVaqV3TBsZPAIIRCU-Q',
   '5:0-0:0',
   '5:0-0:0',
   '5:0-0:0',
   '5:0-0:0',
   '5:0-0:0',
   '5:0-0:0',
   '5:0-0:0']]}
```

what is the syntax allowing me to extract the number of hours from each column (representing days in this case) to calculate the number of business hours in the week inside a new column?

If any clarifications or simpler example needed, please ask.

Edit - tried a solution listed below but the results does not make sens (in the first line for example?)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do your stuff. It saves the new data as float (in hours). With `datetime` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) you can easily calulate times, if you want to.
This applays the function `calculate_hours` to the 7 given columns (days):

```
def calculate_hours(row: pd.Series) -> float:
    try:
        # split the given times to start and end time
        opening_time, closing_time = row.split("-")
        # split hours and minutes
        start_hour, start_minute = opening_time.split(":")
        end_hour, end_minute = closing_time.split(":")
        # calculate start time (in hours)
        start_time = float(start_hour) + float(start_minute) / 60
        # calculate end time (in hours)
        end_time = float(end_hour) + float(end_minute) / 60
        # handle overneight and 24h openings
        if start_time >= end_time:
            end_time += 24
        # return the duration from start time to end time
        return end_time - start_time
    # bare except are not recommended, you should look for your data, what could go wrong
    except:
        return 0.0


# Save the given data to the new column "open"
# sums up values for each day
df["open"] = df["lundi"].apply(calculate_hours) +\
             df["mardi"].apply(calculate_hours) +\
             df["mercredi"].apply(calculate_hours) +\
             df["jeudi"].apply(calculate_hours) +\
             df["vendredi"].apply(calculate_hours) +\
             df["samedi"].apply(calculate_hours) +\
             df["dimanche"].apply(calculate_hours)
```

PS: I used this to "import" your data, it does not look perfect, but i didn't know how to use your data better:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

all = {'index': [0,
                  1,
                  2,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5,
                  6,
                  7,
                  8,
                  9,
                  10,
                  11,
                  12,
                  13,
                  14,
                  15,
                  16,
                  17,
                  18,
                  19],
        'columns': ['restaurant_id',
                    'lundi',
                    'mardi',
                    'mercredi',
                    'jeudi',
                    'vendredi',
                    'samedi',
                    'dimanche'],
        'data': [['lCwqJWMxvIUQt1Re_tDn4w',
                  '0:0-0:0',
                  '0:0-0:0',
                  '0:0-0:0',
                  '0:0-0:0',
                  '0:0-0:0',
                  '0:0-0:0',
                  '0:0-0:0'],
                 ['pd0v6sOqpLhFJ7mkpIaixw',
                  '11:0-20:0',
                  '11:0-20:0',
                  '11:0-20:0',
                  '11:0-20:0',
                  '11:0-22:0',
                  '11:0-22:0',
                  '11:0-17:0'],
                 ['0vhi__HtC2L4-vScgDFdFw',
                  '11:30-22:0',
                  '11:30-22:0',
                  '11:30-22:0',
                  '11:30-22:0',
                  '11:30-22:0',
                  '12:0-22:0',
                  '16:30-21:30'],
                 ['t65yfB9v9fqlhAkLnnUXdg',
                  '11:30-21:0',
                  '11:30-21:0',
                  '11:30-21:0',
                  '11:30-21:0',
                  '11:30-21:0',
                  None,
                  '11:30-21:0'],
                 ['i7_JPit-2kAbtRTLkic2jA',
                  '11:30-22:0',
                  '11:30-22:0',
                  '11:30-23:0',
                  '11:30-23:0',
                  '11:30-23:0',
                  None,
                  None],
                 ['vMh4madPU3qhNX7P7d8WGA', None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                 ['BsvCTCVG7lrzXZ68VyyIcg',
                  '0:0-0:0',
                  '11:0-2:30',
                  '11:0-2:30',
                  '11:0-2:30',
                  '11:0-2:30',
                  '11:0-2:30',
                  '11:0-2:30'],
                 ['es3Fq9KNp6Ry994x4T4ZYg',
                  '6:30-16:0',
                  '6:30-16:0',
                  '6:30-16:0',
                  '6:30-16:0',
                  '6:30-16:0',
                  '7:0-14:0',
                  None],
                 ['Xb7jOAa17xtT_uA4sCCAsg', None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                 ['1vrrpIhpK628PUA0XWWd8g',
                  '9:0-18:0',
                  '9:0-18:0',
                  '9:0-18:0',
                  '9:0-18:0',
                  '9:0-18:0',
                  '9:0-18:0',
                  '9:0-18:0'],
                 ['NYKxikYKbkacWumJ82TxzA',
                  '11:0-2:0',
                  '11:0-2:0',
                  '11:0-2:0',
                  '11:0-2:0',
                  '11:0-2:0',
                  '11:0-2:0',
                  '11:0-2:0'],
                 ['4sRJvmKh43AqMRrjdwEdwA',
                  '11:0-22:0',
                  '11:0-22:0',
                  '11:0-22:0',
                  '11:0-22:0',
                  '11:0-23:0',
                  '11:0-23:0',
                  '11:0-23:0'],
                 ['laac2uH1lQVzBjKFUjuA1Q',
                  '7:0-14:0',
                  '7:0-14:0',
                  '7:0-14:0',
                  '7:0-14:0',
                  '7:0-14:0',
                  '7:0-14:0',
                  '8:0-14:0'],
                 ['vVOoL5H8Fr-qlQv-_DdoMA',
                  '10:0-22:0',
                  '10:0-22:0',
                  '10:0-22:0',
                  '10:0-22:0',
                  '10:0-23:0',
                  '10:0-23:0',
                  '10:0-22:0'],
                 ['k1c4gg8Ri5dre6ruPUKxJQ',
                  '9:0-21:30',
                  '9:0-21:30',
                  '9:0-21:30',
                  '9:0-21:30',
                  '9:0-22:30',
                  '9:0-22:30',
                  '12:0-21:0'],
                 ['x9f9NBMweyyjCQHuc9K4sw',
                  '11:0-17:0',
                  '10:0-17:0',
                  '10:0-17:0',
                  '10:0-17:0',
                  '10:0-18:0',
                  '10:0-18:0',
                  None],
                 ['KWfLQddMBZNoh1bVcgASfA',
                  '12:0-23:0',
                  '12:0-23:0',
                  '12:0-23:0',
                  '12:0-23:0',
                  '12:0-23:0',
                  '12:0-23:0',
                  '12:0-23:0'],
                 ['4ScLXRii_WwBn5PbGBI-eg', None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                 ['LAswzVTnT3uCvnKr-SwxEg', None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                 ['G_wqVaqV3TBsZPAIIRCU-Q',
                  '5:0-0:0',
                  '5:0-0:0',
                  '5:0-0:0',
                  '5:0-0:0',
                  '5:0-0:0',
                  '5:0-0:0',
                  '5:0-0:0']]}


data = all["data"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = all["columns"]
```

Comment: ohh okay i think i understand what you did, but i'm confused how is it possible to manipulate hours as dates and substract them. can you explain a little more what you did in calculate_hours? also, i get AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' when i try to run it

Comment: and how can i output the total hours back the in new column?

Comment: i adde some comments and my way to use your data. The data is written in a new column named "open", so if you print your dataframe you should see it. Where did you get your float error (shich line and which data)?

Comment: the float error came from the NaNs in the dataset. So i tried your solution but in the new column "open", the results does not make sens. I added a screenshot in my post for you to see. I need the total number of hours in the week.

Comment: i changed to `float`, so it may be easier for you. On my machine the second line gives `2 days 16:00:00` (what lokks correct) and now `64` which is the same in hours.